# title of uploaded mp3 in form files

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading a File's Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862645/reading-a-files-metadata)

i have this form where i am uploading mp3 files but i want users to upload music and all details like author,title etc of mp3 should automatically filled in form field.i am using php and want any php/javascript  method which can find out the name of the file from local machine and put that name in my form  title field 
 my form is given below. i dont want users to enter title,author etc

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="http://youshare.ca/music/writestorypost"><p><span class="form_label">Name of the song</span><input type="text" value="" name="title" style="width:400px" class="inputText required"></p><p><span class="form_label">Description</span>
<textarea class="rich" style="width:580px" rows="18" name="form_content"></textarea>
</p><p><span class="form_label">Tags</span>
    <input type="text" value="" style="width:300px" name="tags" class="inputText">
    <span>Multiple tags should be Separated with commas(,)</span>
    </p>
        <p><label>Upload</label><input type="file" name="song">
        <span>Only mp3 is accepted</span></p>
        <p><label>Music source</label>
        <input type="radio" checked="1" value="own" name="musicsource">My own 
        <input type="radio" value="others" name="musicsource">From another musician
        </p>
        <div style="display:none" id="ms_others">
        <p><label>Musician name</label><input name="musician"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="ms_own">
        <p></p>
        </div>
        <p><label>Picture (Optional)</label><input type="file" name="picture">
        <span>A picture about the song or the musician</span></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("input[value='own']").click(
            function() {
            $("#ms_others").hide();
            $("#ms_own").fadeIn();
            }
            );
      $("input[value='others']").click(
            function() {
            $("#ms_own").hide();
            $("#ms_others").fadeIn();
            }
            );
    })
  </script><p><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button"></p><input type="hidden" value="935" name="page_id"></form>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code here and only post that which is essential to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to populate your MP3's details after the file is uploaded, unless they manually type in all information.

On the PHP side, you can install the following: [PHP ID3](http://php.net/manual/en/book.id3.php)

There are examples there on how to read ID3 tags from files.

Comment: i dont agree with you. you just upload any videos in youtube .the moment you uploaded the title comes automatically however the file was just started getting uploaded