# Music file details extract in PHP

Tags: php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert Song</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" 
enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
Select the Song : <input type="file" name="file">
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
include("database.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
     echo $name;

     $sql = mysql_query("insert into songs (name) values ('$name')");
     if($sql)
     {
        echo "<br>inserted successfully";
     }
     else
     {
         echo "<br>not";
     }
 }
 ?>
```

Someone explain me how can i get details of a mp3 file(like name,artist,size,etc) in PHP from the code as written above.

Comment: Please protect yourself against SQL injection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a File's Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862645/reading-a-files-metadata)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.id3.php

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).